# Drupal 7: How to sort nodes on nearest date of referencing entities?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-views, entityreference

Here's something I can't wrap my head around, and wonder if it is possible at all:

- I have a content type **Events**. All events have a date-field.
- Each Event also has an entity-reference-field to choose an overarching **Series**.
- Now, with *Views* I want to sort the latter **Series** based on the event-dates (from Events that reference this Series). As such, the series associated with the first upcoming events (compared to 'today'), should be displayed first.

I tried the module *Views field view* and it does output the first upcoming event for each Series, but it can't be used as a sorting criteria. Are there any other options to achieve this?

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to handle this using a relationship.
You can find these under the 'Advanced' tab on the right side of the Views UI. You'll want to add a relationship to the Series, then add a the date field to your list of sorts. You'll notice a new dropdown option in the options form for relationship. Select your Series here, and save the sort.

Comment: Thanks! This indeed did work. But since there can be more Events on a Series, it duplicated the Series when showing them. Guess I'll have to fix that with Aggregation or Distinct.